# Unable to find error in my latex code

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

Hello LaTeX Community,

I was working on a template and almost finished it, but there was a glitch in my code and I was unable to find it. While rendering the code, the `\textbf{Question \questionnumber:} \questiontext`  was not rendering properly. The `\questionnumber` was not displayed in the output.

Current o/p: `Question :`
Desired o/p: `Question 1 :`

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=1.25cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}

\makeatletter

% DEFINE KEY FOR mcqimgsideFourOne %

\makeatletter
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{questionnumber}{\def\questionnumber{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{questiontext}{\def\questiontext{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgwidth}{\def\imgwidth{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgheight}{\def\imgheight{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{img}{\def\img{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgCaption}{\def\imgCaption{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionA}{\def\optionA{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionB}{\def\optionB{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionC}{\def\optionC{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionD}{\def\optionD{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{author}{\def\author{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{slot}{\def\slot{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{leftmini}{\def\leftmini{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{rightmini}{\def\rightmini{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mcqimgsideFourOne}[1]{
  \setkeys{mcqimgsideFourOne}{
    questionnumber =,
    questiontext =,
    imgwidth =,
    imgheight =,
    img =,
    imgCaption =,
    optionA =,
    optionB =,
    optionC =,
    optionD =,
    author =,
    slot =,
    leftmini =, 
    rightmini =, 
    #1
  }

  \vspace{2.5mm}
  \begin{raggedright}
    \textbf{Author:} \author \hfill \textbf{Slot:} \slot\\
  \end{raggedright}
  \vspace{\baselineskip}

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\leftmini\textwidth}
    \textbf{Question \questionnumber:} \questiontext
      \vspace{2mm} \\
      (a) \medskip \optionA\\
      (b) \medskip \optionB\\
      (c) \medskip \optionC\\
      (d) \medskip \optionD\\
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightmini\textwidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=\imgheight]{\img}
    \captionsetup{type=figure, labelformat=empty} 
    \caption{\imgCaption} 
    \label{fig:sample}
  \end{minipage}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        Start Question
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        Question [ 1 ]
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% start-of-question
\mcqimgsideFourOne{
  questionnumber={1}, 
  questiontext={Which of the following is an example of a mammal?},
  imgwidth={3cm},
  imgheight={3cm},
  img={example-image-a},
  imgCaption={A sample image of a mammal},
  optionA={Fish},
  optionB={Bird},
  optionC={Dog},
  optionD={Insect},
  author={Author 1},
  slot={C},
  leftmini={0.6},
  rightmini={0.4},
} 
% end-of-question  

\end{document}
```

Note:
I'm new to LaTeX and this community, if you have any suggestions or any different approach/ideas from my current approach, feel free to comment your thoughts and ideas it will help me to improve my code quality.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ignore Community; they got confused because your MWE isn't quite as minimal as it could be.  I'm  not quite sure why, but your first key to `\mcqimgsideFourOne{` isn't getting read (try switching `questionnumber={1}` with any other line).  You can fix this by putting a `%` after the `\mcqimgsideFourOne{`.

Comment: Welcome! Don't you get an error when you try to compile this?

Comment: Note that it isn't a great idea to redefine `\author` as it is a standard command. It would be safer to use a different name for the macro e.g. `\qauthor` or whatever.

Comment: It would be better to use a list (e.g. `enumerate`) rather than hard-coding `(a)` etc. You might have a look at `enumitem`. And `\\ ` shouldn't generally be used to end lines outside special environments.

Comment: @Teepeemm i have tried adding % at the end of the command ```\newcommand{\mcqimgsideFourOne}[1]{%```  but it didn't make any difference. 

if i reorder the questionnumber and questiontext, then questiontext gets disappeared; whatever i had as a first parameter it gets disappeared from the output

Comment: @cfr No, there was no error thrown while compiling it. Point taken, once i fix this disappearing issue i will rename the author. i tried ```enumerate``` first but i need only 4 options and it goin to change so i stick to ```(a)``` and it will be easy for the other team members to use it too.

Comment: Hmm ... That's weird. I got a very clear compilation error concerning an undefined key.

Comment: If `\questionnumber` is a counter, I think you can get it to print using `\arabic{\questionnumber}`.  (Not tested.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\def\questionnumber{#1}`. But the problem is it isn't getting defined at all because the key-value parser looks for ` questionnumber` due to the uncommented line ending, rather than `questionnumber`.

Comment: fixed the issue, used ```\NewDocumentCommand``` from the ```xparse``` instead of ```\newcommand```and enclosed the key setting in
```\begingroup``` and ```\endgroup``` to limit the scope of the macro, it worked.

thanks for the suggestions @cfr, @teepeemm, @barbara beeton

Comment: You need `\mcqimgsideFourOne{%`. You're putting the `%` in the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're adding two spaces in front of the first key you give at use time. The first is added by the faulty definition of `\mcqimgsideFourOne`, the second by the usage of it. The space at use-time shouldn't be an issue, and it wouldn't be if the definition was correct. But `xkeyval` (as most other key=value parsers) strips only a single space from either end of a key or value. Hence it is searched for `␣questionnumber` which isn't defined.

If you fix your definition your usage works (note that this answer only fixes the error, it doesn't improve anything else):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}

\geometry{top=2.5cm, bottom=1.25cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm}

\makeatletter

% DEFINE KEY FOR mcqimgsideFourOne %

\makeatletter
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{questionnumber}{\def\questionnumber{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{questiontext}{\def\questiontext{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgwidth}{\def\imgwidth{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgheight}{\def\imgheight{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{img}{\def\img{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{imgCaption}{\def\imgCaption{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionA}{\def\optionA{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionB}{\def\optionB{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionC}{\def\optionC{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{optionD}{\def\optionD{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{author}{\def\author{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{slot}{\def\slot{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{leftmini}{\def\leftmini{#1}}
\define@key{mcqimgsideFourOne}{rightmini}{\def\rightmini{#1}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mcqimgsideFourOne}[1]{
  \setkeys{mcqimgsideFourOne}{
    questionnumber =,
    questiontext =,
    imgwidth =,
    imgheight =,
    img =,
    imgCaption =,
    optionA =,
    optionB =,
    optionC =,
    optionD =,
    author =,
    slot =,
    leftmini =,
    rightmini =,% THIS LINE CHANGED
    #1
  }

  \vspace{2.5mm}
  \begin{raggedright}
    \textbf{Author:} \author \hfill \textbf{Slot:} \slot\\
  \end{raggedright}
  \vspace{\baselineskip}

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\leftmini\textwidth}
    \textbf{Question \questionnumber:} \questiontext
      \vspace{2mm} \\
      (a) \medskip \optionA\\
      (b) \medskip \optionB\\
      (c) \medskip \optionC\\
      (d) \medskip \optionD\\
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\rightmini\textwidth}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\imgwidth, height=\imgheight]{\img}
    \captionsetup{type=figure, labelformat=empty}
    \caption{\imgCaption}
    \label{fig:sample}
  \end{minipage}
}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        Start Question
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%                        Question [ 1 ]
%-----------------------------------------------------------
% start-of-question
\mcqimgsideFourOne{
  questionnumber={1},
  questiontext={Which of the following is an example of a mammal?},
  imgwidth={3cm},
  imgheight={3cm},
  img={example-image-a},
  imgCaption={A sample image of a mammal},
  optionA={Fish},
  optionB={Bird},
  optionC={Dog},
  optionD={Insect},
  author={Author 1},
  slot={C},
  leftmini={0.6},
  rightmini={0.4},
}
% end-of-question

\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: It is not always necessary to use `keyval` or `xkeyval` when you are defining your own template (or document class). If you have enough knowledge of LaTeX, you can parse the strings with your own code. Then you can eliminate things like the double space, detect whether a length setting is actually usable as a length, and so forth. I already do this with my own code. And, the error messages are custom, tailored to the exact problem.

Comment: @rallg depending on the code/task in question and the coders proficiency, using a package for parsing is a very good idea. You're using well-tested stuff (if you pick your packages wisely, for instance I'd not pick `(x)keyval` for key=value parsing) instead of custom code, so chances are you end up with more robust solutions. Also, if OP has issues with extra white space as in the question, I doubt the code quality will be high enough to implement completely custom solutions (yet). Last note: Your comment should've been posted under the question, not my answer, imho.

Comment: Yes, should have been posted up there. Nice to know that I'm not the only one who would prefer something other than (x)keyval.

Comment: @rallg well, I'd only use two different key=value systems nowadays, and a third one if I happen to use Ti*k*Z: `expkv` (my own package), `l3keys`, or `pgfkeys` (only for directly interfacing stuff that uses Ti*k*Z).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning those other packages. I do not use TikZ or pgf, and anything with `l3` in it gives me the shakes. Only reason I roll my own, is that I can customize the errors and warnings easily, and also calculate likely defaults for bad key values (based on good key values). Although this can be done along with (x)keyval, it is simply easier to do it directly.